# Wordpress: Limit posts per page in category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

In my index.php I use this code to limit the posts per page and it works without any problems:

```
$showposts = 5;
$do_not_show_stickies = 1;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('category__in' => $cat, 'showposts' => $showposts, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged);

$loop2query = new WP_Query($args);

query_posts($args); if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="blogpost"> ... </div>

<?php endwhile; endif;
posts_nav_link(); // Navigating the pages with $showposts each. ?>
```

The same code did not work in category.php so I changed it to the following but it still does not work:

```
$showposts = 4;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
    <div class="blogpost"> ... </div>

<?php } }

else { ?>
    <p>There are no blog posts in this category.</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php posts_nav_link(); // Navigating the pages with $showposts each. ?>
```

I tried to change the line with `if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> [...]` in category.php to make it similar to that line in index.php but nothing I tried worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpress has a setting for this, found in the admin area under **SETTINGS -> READING -> Blog pages show at most**

You can use this instead of custom-modifying your queries. It may make it a little easier to maintain your project down the road.

Comment: Thank you! I did not even think about a solution like this

Answer (score 1):

Use the `posts_per_page` argument ([Codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query))

```
$args = array('category__in' => $cat, 'posts_per_page' => $showposts, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you first example, you actually have two queries : `new WP_query`, then `query_posts`, so you need to get rid of one of them, as this is redundant. In the second exemple, it is the contrary, you do not have any query (although WordPress might execute one by default, depending on where this page is called). So anyway, there is no point in using `$showposts` in your 2nd example, as you are not executing a query after... 
`if (have_posts())` is generally used to treat a default (not visible in your page code) loop from WordPress or to treat a query that you declare just before (generally with `query_posts()`).
As @Samuel is saying, the argument to use is `posts_per_page`, but I think you are not there yet and you should first start to learn how to execute a query, so you can start by reading the WordPress codex on `query_posts`, it will be the best place to go first : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts.